# Why is my animation (animator) delayed?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I made a game and when you die the score moves from top right to the middle of the screen using an animation. When you press Retry I reverse the animation by by setting the a speed parameter which is used as a speed multiplier in AnimationState.

While the parameter switches value (from 1.0 to -1.0 and or the other way around) the animation has a delay. I also noticed the longer you wait pressing retry, the longer it'll take for the animation to start. I do have to mention the animation doesn't have a transition to an idle state, so it probably means the animation time is moving > 1.0. I tried setting normalizedTime, but this didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Inspector]
[image: Relevant code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay apparently I had to use `ForceStateNormalizedTime()` as `normalizedTime` was going above 1.0f and below 0.0f.